# how to use GridViewUpdateEventArgs inside a property method VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I wanna show drop down list on the footer of my GridView.

```
    aspx code:
 <FooterTemplate>                                                      
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddSrc" runat="server">    
 </asp:DropDownList>                                                   
 </FooterTemplate>



 'VB Code
         Protected Sub gvID_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
             If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                 If e.Row.DataItem IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim ddSrc As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddSrc"), DropDownList)      
                        If ddSrc IsNot Nothing Then
                             ddSrc.DataTextField = "Name"
                             ddSrc.DataValueField = "Id"
                             ddSrc.DataSource = GetData()
                             ddSrc.DataBind()
                        End If
                 End If
             End If
         End Sub
```

I have used above code behind code used to load my dropdown list but getting issue like 
**"object reference not set to an instance of an object**" over the line "**ddSrc.DataTextField = "Name"**" during runtime.

I have edited  my question to easy understand.

Comment: @Jacooobley fine. Can u paste any sample code for the same

Comment: Posted code in an answer

Comment: Please elaborate more what do you want to accomplish here?

Comment: @EmadMokhtar I have edited my question for easy understanding let me know your comments

Comment: Yeah now anyone can know where is the issue and @Damith get it well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to load droupdown list on RowDataBound event of grid view

```
Protected Sub gvID_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        If e.Row.DataItem IsNot Nothing Then
           Dim ddSrc As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddSrc"), DropDownList)      
               If ddSrc IsNot Nothing Then
                    ddSrc.DataTextField = "Name"
                    ddSrc.DataValueField = "Id"
                    ddSrc.DataSource = GetData()
                    ddSrc.DataBind()
               End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error over the line ddSrc.DataTextField = "Name"

Comment: if it is footer then you need to compare with `DataControlRowType.Footer` not `DataControlRowType.DataRow`

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, but could it mean it requires a 'new' in the declaration?

```
Dim e As New GridViewUpdateEventArgs
```

If it hasnt been created yet, you wont be able to assign a variable to it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But getting below error 'Argument not specified for parameter 'rowIndex' of 'Public Sub New(rowIndex As Integer)' on the e from Dim e As New GridViewUpdateEventArgs